# how do i run script after successful build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins-plugins

I am running automated builds in jenkins after successful build the jars are copying in to my scp repository.

I configured in **post build** action publish artifacts in to scp repository. Everything is going fine.

But I want to stop my dev server before copying artifacts in to my dev server from jenkins.

Is it possible to stop my dev server from jenkins ?

Comment: is your dev server a separate machine?

Comment: Add one more build step `Execute Shell`, after your main build process. Use `ssh user@server -ppassword <command to be executed on server>`. Let me know if this gives a clue for you, or like am I in right direction in helping you.

Comment: do you use master/slave mode for this ? How you control the devserver ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for an answer but you can install [plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) to run a script post build. 
You can install the plugin by browsing to Manage Jenkin -> Manage Plugin on Jenkins. Then select **Available** tab. Search for the **Post Build Task** plugin and install